# Firebase Auth returning 400 (Bad Request) when signing in

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

In my app, whenever the user tries to sign in using an email and password that does not exist in the system. I receive a 400 error. The 400 error only occurs when I have an @ symbol in the email input.
Here is the error: [Full Error Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDEpr.png)

Here is my code:

```
const loginForm = document.querySelector('#login');

loginForm.addEventListener("submit", e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const email = document.querySelector("#login #email").value;
        const password = document.querySelector("#login #password").value;
        console.log(email, password);
        // Perform Login
        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((userCredential) => {
            console.log('User sign in successful');
            // userCredential has userID, email, display name
            setFormMessage(loginForm, "success", "");
        }).catch((error) => { 
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            setFormMessage(loginForm, "error", errorMessage);
        });
        
    });
```

I have enabled email / password in the firebase project as a sign-in method. I also get another 400 error when creating a new account with an existing email. I don't think it should be a 400 error because when the input has no @ symbol, the error is just a normal auth error and doesn't show an error in the console. Need some help! thank you.